# Choosing criteria in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two excel files that I linked together to make a Query in Access.

```
Table One     Table Two
Name  ID      Name   ID
John  342     John   342
Mike  234     Mike   234
Mich  980     Mich   980
Jenn  098     Quay   309
Anna  145     Pond   612
              Lope   546
              Anna   145
```

How do i set the criteria in the access query so that they match the ID and only show me the names on the left matching the right. Anything from table two that doesn't match with table one to disregard?

If I have the following query:

```
Name          Name
Table one     Table two
```

I get the following result:

```
John   John
Mike   John
Mich   John
Jenn   John
Anna   John
John   Mike
Mike   Mike
Mich   Mike
Jenn   Mike
Anna   Mike
```

and so forth... So i am figuring i have to set a criteria... which is where i am stuck at... any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an INNER JOIN:

```
 SELECT [Table 1].Name, [Table 2].Name 
 FROM [Table 1] 
 INNER JOIN [Table 2]
 ON [Table 1].Name = [Table 2].Name
```

You can create this query in MS Access by adding both tables to the query design window and then dragging the field you want to match from one table to the next or by switching to SQL view and typing or pasting SQL.

More information:
[Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)